# How to verify the content type of the image file stored in ZIP archive?

Tags: php, zip, mime-types

Below is the code which I used to read a zip file. Zip file contains images. Below code works fine. I went through the PHP doc too. There isn't a way to verity the type of the particular entry that you read using `zip_entry_read`

```
if ($zip) 
{
    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) 
    {

        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) 
        {

            $imgContent = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry)); // File Contents

            /* how to verify it's an image before image manipulation ? */

            /* image manipulation code goes here */

            zip_entry_close($zip_entry);

        }

    }

    zip_close($zip);

}
```

My problem is how can I verify that it's an image that I read using `zip_entry_read` function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach:

```
$imageInfo = getimagesizefromstring($imgContent);
if ($imageInfo !== false) { 
  // that's an image
}
```

Additionally, you may want to check the image's MIME type (for setting the `Content-Type` header properly, for example):

```
$imageMimeType = image_type_to_mime_type($imageInfo[2]);
```

Note that both [**getimagesizefromstring()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php) and [**image_type_to_mime_type()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php) require `GD` extension to be in place - but then again, you probably have it loaded already.